# Why can't I run command “nvcc --version" in docker-CUDA Container?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, bash, cuda

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04，and I've already installed nvidia driver and `nvidia-docker`, but cannot detect CUDA.

```
$ docker run -it --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.0-cudnn7-runtime-ubuntu18.04 /bin/bash
root@7c0be9bfaeec:/# nvcc --version
bash: nvcc: command not found
```

Also I cannot detect CUDNN in the Docker container:

```
root@694cefcad33a:/# cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2
cat: /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h: No such file or directory
```

However when I,run `nvidia-smi`, it worked!

```
root@7c0be9bfaeec:/# nvidia-smi
Thu Dec 19 04:51:23 2019
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.44 Driver Version: 440.44 CUDA Version: 10.2 |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU Name Persistence-M| Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage | GPU-Util Compute M. |
```

Comment: Did you alter your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH as the cuda install instructions indicated?  The dnn is probably another install done after the CUDA install, what did you do for that?

Comment: I install files in /usr/local/cuda-10.0 in docker container.This means it install files already.  You are correct,Due to the operation mechanism of docker, its environment variables are empty. I'm thinking about how to pass in environment variables. It seems that it can only be done through the command line, because the latest NVIDIA docker does not support docker compose.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to connect docker in pycharm, load GPU, and develop TensorFlow-GPU code. At present, it is very difficult. The latest NVIDIA docker does not support docker compose! My sky!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are running the `runtime` tag of `nvidia/cuda` Docker image, which doesn't include the development tools `nvcc` and the CUDA headers you're trying to access. That image only contains the runtime libraries needed to execute a CUDA application. I guess you can access the development tools from the tag `latest`.

Try this command:

```
$ docker run -it --gpus all nvidia/cuda:latest bash
```

ETA: The header files may be installed at a different location. I suggest that you need not worry about the `CUDNN_MAJOR` value. If you absolutely need it, try:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mlocate
sudo updatedb
sudo locate cudnn.h
```

If you find a result (eg `/a/b/cudnn.h`), then substitute that location in place of the `cat` command you commented. Like this:

```
cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2 #This is the old command
cat /a/b/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2 #This is the new command, with the file you found
```

Also, you're showing an example of Useless Use of `cat` ([UUOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)). You can do this instead:

```
grep -A 2 CUDNN_MAJOR /a/b/cudnn.h # Avoid UUOC
```

PS: @optimus From the Docker image you tried to install, `nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04`, you could see that the major version number of CUDNN is 7. Just thought it might be useful to you.

PPS: If you can't find the CUDNN header, you might not have it installed. Try installing it by following [this guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html).

Comment: docker run nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04         and run nvcc --version,it works!!  However，I  run:cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2     It show errors

Comment: @optimus check my edit.

Comment: Thanks very much!
@Mukesh Sai Kumar